# SSIS Expression builder for MULTI line file ( Exec Process Task)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl, executeprocesstask

My global task to create config file for WinSCP process, and it should be multi lines (no options). I try to use Expression builder for CMD/Echo to do this. And still file, tried all option with and without /C flag which is critical for SSIS cmd task. I have option to have task for each line and it's by back plan, but trying to see if I can come up and learn how to do this in single box.  I example below I can create multi line Expression using  `+ " "` combo where second quotes on new line. But it's still not good for whole task, Looks like `CMD /C` need single line ??

All info displayed in pic below:

[image]

This is arguments I'm using now with WinSCP executable in System task.

```
open ud12345d264d7b8@magdaflyn.sharefileftp.com
option transfer binary
put c:\SFTP\Magda_Members_20190901.csv   "/Business Intelligence Share/Zbignev/"
close
exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Creating multi-line expression

In order to add new lines in SSIS expression you must use the carriage return and line feed  characters `\r\n`:

```
"/C Echo line11 \r\n /C Echo " + @[User::Var3] + "Line222 \r\n /C Echo Line3 > Config.dat"
```

#### Executing multiple commands

If adding new lines didn't work, you can use `&&` operator to run multiple command using CMD:

- [SSIS: Execute Multiple Commands with 1 line in Execute Process Task (Arguments)](https://mahalenilesh.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/ssis-execute-multiple-commands-with-1-line-in-execute-process-task-arguments/)

#### Workaround

If all what I mentioned above didn't work, then try saving the whole command into a batch file, and execute this batch file from the Execute Process Task.

Comment: Tx Hadi, combo with single `&` worked !. Before I had box for each line.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two lines using this syntax:

```
/c "echo line1 && echo line2" > config.dat
```

---

Though, you do not need to create a *config file* for WinSCP. All WinSCP options can be configured on its command-line. *So this may be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578).*

And while it's not clear, you may actually be creating a *[script file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#using_scripting)*, not a config file. You can instead specify all WinSCP commands on WinSCP command-line using [`/command` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting):

```
winscp.com /command "open ud12345d264d7b8@magdaflyn.sharefileftp.com" "option transfer binary" "put c:\SFTP\Magda_Members_20190901.csv ""/Business Intelligence Share/Zbignev/""" "close" "exit"
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a command-line sample for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).

---

See also WinSCP article [SFTP Task for SSIS/SSDT](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis).

Though you actually better use WinSCP .NET assembly instead of scripting in SSIS. See [Using WinSCP .NET Assembly from SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis).